# APPFabric client communication error?

Tags: exception, client, appfabric

I have configured 2 AppFabric instances and try to connect from a test client to the cache.
At first, I had trouble establishing the cache using the DataCacheFactory, but after opening the 22233-22235 ports in the firewall I have managed to get the cache using the DataCacheFactory.

As soon as I try to use the cache for a very small object (using a simple get), I get the following with a null InnerException:
ErrorCode:SubStatus:The connection was terminated, possibly due to server or network problems or serialized Object size is greater than MaxBufferSize on server. Result of the request is unknown.

I don't believe it's the MaxBufferSize issue (I also modified the transportProperties in the config just to make sure), but on the other hand - I'm able to get the cache, which I believe should indicate that the client can communicate with the server. So what is it? -How can I get more details on this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Nir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work!
All I needed to do was just to add the host names, as appear in ClusterConfig file to the hosts file of the client, and that's it!

Hope that helps anyone,
Nir.